# Replacing entries in a numpy array with their quantile index with python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, quantile

I have a one-dimensional numpy array with numbers, and I want each number replaced with the index of the quantile it belongs to.

This is my code for quintile indices:

```
import numpy as np

def get_quintile_indices( a ):

    result = np.ones( a.shape[ 0 ] ) * 4

    quintiles = [
        np.percentile( a, 20 ),
        np.percentile( a, 40 ),
        np.percentile( a, 60 ),
        np.percentile( a, 80 )
    ]

    for q in quintiles:
        result -= np.less_equal( a, q ) * 1

    return result

a = np.array( [ 58, 54, 98, 76, 35, 13, 62, 18, 62, 97, 44, 43 ] )
print get_quintile_indices( a )
```

Output:

```
[ 2.  2.  4.  4.  0.  0.  3.  0.  3.  4.  1.  1.]
```

You see I start with an array initialized with the highest possible index and for every quintile cutpoint substract 1 from each entry that is less or equal than the quintile cutpoint. Is there a better way to do this? A build-in function that can be used to map numbers against a list of cutpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, we can generate those `quintiles` in one go -

```
quintiles = np.percentile( a, [20,40,60,80] )
```

For the final step to get the offsets, we can simply use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and this might be the built-in you were looking for, like so -

```
out = np.searchsorted(quintiles, a)
```

Alternatively, a direct translation of your loopy code to a vectorized version would be with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
# Use broadcasting to perform those comparisons in one go.
# Then, simply sum along the first axis and subtract from 4. 
out = 4 - (quintiles[:,None] >=  a).sum(0)
```

If `quintiles` is a list, we need to assign it as an array and then use `broadcasting`, like so -

```
out = 4 - (np.asarray(quintiles)[:,None] >=  a).sum(0)
```

Comment: Should be `out = np.searchsorted( quintiles, a )` though.

Comment: @daign Well if we generate `quintiles` with `np.percentile( a, [20,40,60,80] )`, then `quintiles` would be an array, then `quintiles.searchsorted(a)` would also work. But yes, if `quintiles` is  a list like the way you have in your code, then we need to use `np.searchsorted( quintiles, a )`.

Comment: Strangely `np.percentile( a, [20,40,60,80] )` does not give me an array, but a list. Is there a difference between python versions? I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: @daign What's your NumPy version?

Comment: `>>> numpy.version.version
'1.6.1'`
Because I'm still using Ubuntu 12.04 :)

Comment: @daign Let me edit the post with it anyway for future readers with old versions :)

Comment: Ok, and the alternative solution has to read `out = 4 - (np.array( quintiles )[:,None] >= a).sum(0)`. Same problem.